# Check if fs.mqueue.msg_max must be increased and do it

Tags: bash, mqueue

I need to run a program with a bash script. This program may require a larger than default message queue.

I know I can increase it with:

```
sudo sysctl fs.mqueue.msg_max=3000
```

And I could, for instance, check it with:

```
echo  "$(sysctl fs.mqueue.msg_max)"
```

which would print, for instance `fs.mqueue.msg_max = 100"`

I need to create a conditional `if` to increase the size if it is less than a threshold value (and do nothing otherwise).

I expected it to look like:

```
queue_size=$(sysctl fs.mqueue.msg_max)

if (($queue_size < 3000))
then
    sudo sysctl fs.mqueue.msg_max 3000
else
    echo "message queue large enough at $queue_size"
fi
```

But this returns:

`((: fs.mqueue.msg_max = 200 < 3000: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".mqueue.msg_max = 200 < 3000")`

As `queue_size` received an object which is not the queue size, but something I don't understand nor know how to manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract only the number from your output.  You can do this with `awk`:

```
queue_size=$(sysctl fs.mqueue.msg_max | awk -F= '{print $2}')
```

or `cut`:

```
queue_size=$(sysctl fs.mqueue.msg_max | cut -d= -f2)
```

or simply with bash parameter expansion:

```
queue_size=$(sysctl fs.mqueue.msg_max)
queue_size=${queue_size#*=}
```